# Screw stuck on backflow test cock - thoughts before replacing?

Tags: plumbing, sprinkler-system, irrigation

I was draining my backflow prevention device before a deep freeze. I removed the caps on the test cocks and got sprayed by a nice gusher of water from one... apparently the test cock has been open for years, and water completely contained by just the screw-on cap.

Anyways, the test cock is stuck in the open position, and opens/shuts via flathead screwdriver. A few attempts to turn it have just worn some of the slot away.

Any thoughts/tips on getting it to turn? I'm guessing I can just buy a replacement test cock, but was wondering if there were any suggestions I should go through first. The test cock looks similar to this one from amazon:

[image: Similar test cock from amazon]

Comment: Can you find make/model info on the specific backflow preventer you have?

Comment: Could try a manual impact driver. They work with  the combination of impact force and turning force. You hold it on the screw and tap. The tapping forces the screw to turn, the tapping holds the driver on the screw. Often used to remove screws that hold brake rotors on

Comment: Oooh... I had no idea this was a thing. Those are slick. Unfortunately the test cock is in an irrigation enclosure such that I don't think I could tap with a hammer, but I definitely could after removing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a right angled screw driver with a long handle for applying maximum force to the valve.

Here's a DIY version: attach a locking pliers (vise grip) to the handle of a screw driver. You should now be able to press the slot-head forcefully into the valve slot while wrenching it counterclockwise (loose).

If you can shut the water off before the back flow valve you could than remove the test port and work on it more comfortably (in a vice).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll try this before moving on to removal.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly an answer to the question as asked, but…

Preventative measure… go round the house at least twice a year & just cycle each one open/closed a few times. Most houses should have similar in-line stop-cocks on every tap (faucet) inlet so check under sinks, baths, water heater etc.
They get sticky after a while, especially in hard water areas, but just cycling them every so often will prevent this happening again. 15 mins twice a year will save all this hassle of one stuck solid.

Do the same with your main water stop cock too. This will be more like a regular tap/faucet, with a few turns between open & closed. Cycle the full range once or twice then open it right up then close it back a quarter turn. Don't leave it jammed fully-open or it will quite quickly seize.